# Is Parallel.forEach(DataTable.AsEnumerable() thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

when used as follows

```
Parallel.ForEach(DataTable.AsEnumerable(), dr => {

    string str = dr["field1"].ToString();
     //.... other stuff
    dr["f1"] = o.A;
    dr["f2"] = o.B;
    dr["f3"] = o.C;

});
```

where each thread works on its own datarow

I would assume not but but there's this saying about assumptions....

Comment: `DataTable` is an extremely complicated beast.

Comment: let me take a guess, when deploy application on more than one processors. may be stupid answer.

Comment: "assumptions make an ass out of `u` and `mptions`"? Psst.. the saying is about "assume" not "assumptions" ;)

Comment: @SLaks, DataTable is complicated but also very flexible - the source of its complexity :) just trying to get some color on the this specific situation though !

Comment: @Kumar: Yes.  But therefore, it is very unlikely to be threadsafe.

Comment: AsEnumerable() is 100% _not_ thread safe when used as the iteration target in a Parallel.ForEach. Out of 3000 unique rows in a datatable, it will consistently produce less than 2800 _unique_ records despite producing a total count of 3000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f2d84ta.aspx) of the DataRow class definitively states that

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must
>   synchronize any write operations.

Can't get any more specific than that.

In any case, parallel writing to a Datatable is probably not going to scale well. Scalability suffers when you have multiple threads accessing shared state and a single datatable is quite obviously shared state. What's more, unless you work with NUMA hardware your CPU cores will contend for access to the same memory bus.

A much better solution is to return any results from the parallel processing (the "other stuff" ) in a separate structure (e.g. [one of the concurrent collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718.aspx)) and apply the changes from a single thread when the loop finishes.

Another option is to use PLINQ to calculate the results and and iterate over them with a simple foreach to apply the changes back to the DataTable.

An even better solution would be to discard the original datatable entirely and return a new object that contains the fields you require. Unless your code requires the result to be a DataTable, you could simply return the results as an IEnumerable

Comment: If I understand your answer: if for example I needed to modify column X in a data table that contained 200 rows, I could pull the value out of column X for all 200 rows and store it in a concurrent collection, then do a Parallel.For() on that concurrent collection to change the value, then loop on a single thread to update the original DataTable's column X from the values in the concurrent collection?

Comment: No, the opposite. There's no problem reading the values from multiple threads so there's no need to extract them. Assuming there really is a need to process 200 values in parallel, you should collect the results of the processing in a concurrent collection, then apply them back to the table from a single thread.

Comment: 200 was just a random number I thought of but its more like many thousands. In my situation, I have a table in the database where 1 column in that table is encrypted. I load all the rows from this table in the db into a DataTable and I then need to loop through all rows and decrypt that column - so fairly simple problem. I think I understand your comments in that I can concurrently read the values out and decrypt them but to update the origin rows and column, I'll have to do that in a single thread.

Answer (score 4):

[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is not thread safe for write operations. When you concurrently change rows you will be changing the state of the DataTable hence this will cause problems.

Comment: in general yes, but each thread is working on a different row so there is no concurrent op on the row per se, hence the ques about this specific scenario

Comment: @Kumar Even though each thread is working on a different row, the row is contained in the DataTable and when you have write operations on this row the state of the DataTable is affected.

Comment: @Kumar: Not specifically.  If you're interested, look at the [source](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/DataRow@cs/1305376/DataRow@cs).  Good luck; it's extremely complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If any of those columns are indexed, it is definitely unsafe.
If not, it *might* be safe, but I don't think so.

Comment: what do you mean by "if ... columns are indexed" ? the access pattern is as shown above

Comment: @Kumar: `DataTable` has indices, just like SQL Server.  Modifying an indexed column is definitely unsafe, even across rows.

Comment: the column defs are static so no worries on that front, thought that was the case in an app built using .net 2, guessing the perf shd be even better in .net 4

Comment: @Kumar: Wrong on both counts.  ADO.Net DataSets did not change at all in .Net 4.

Comment: ??? wrong about what here? it was a guess ! and if you poke around you will find there are internal changes even if the public interface is unchanged, cheers !