# System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have a foreach.

It only put data into datatable
but it will have exception .

How to fix it?

thanks

```
   Parallel.ForEach(this.dt.AsEnumerable(), opt, r =>
  string inTime = string.Empty;
                string outTime = string.Empty;
                string shiftID = string.Empty;
                string shiftintime = string.Empty;
                string shiftouttime = string.Empty;
                decimal leaveHours = 0;
                string tempNight = string.Empty;
                CommandAPI_Prg.GetShiftID(r["EmployeeID"].ToString(), r["CDate"].ToDateTime(), out shiftID); // 取班別
                CommandAPI_Prg.LogBoxTime(Env.User.Factory, r["EmployeeID"].ToString(), r["CDate"].ToDateTime(), out inTime, out outTime); // 取刷卡時間
                CommandAPI_Prg.DayOfShift2(shiftID, out shiftintime, out shiftouttime); // 取班別時間
                DataTable dayOfLeave = CommandAPI_Prg.DayOfLeave(Env.User.Factory, r["EmployeeID"].ToString(), r["CDate"].ToDateTime()); // 取請假資訊
                DataTable dayOfOverTime = CommandAPI_Prg.DayOfOverTime(Env.User.Factory, r["EmployeeID"].ToString(), r["CDate"].ToDateTime()); // 取加班資訊

                r["ShiftID"] = shiftID; // 實際班表
                r["shiftintime"] = shiftintime;
                r["shiftouttime"] = shiftouttime;
                r["InTime"] = inTime;
                r["OutTime"] = outTime;
}
             );
```

I keep getting the exception below :

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
Parameter name: index

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 索引超出範圍。必須為非負數且小於集合的大小。
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.RecordManager.NewRecordBase()
   at System.Data.DataTable.NewRecord(Int32 sourceRecord)
   at System.Data.DataRow.BeginEditInternal()
   at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(DataColumn column, Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(String columnName, Object value)
   at Sci.PamsPH.Payroll.PayrollP01.<ButOK_Click>b__6_1(DataRow r) in D:\SystemGit2017\PamsPH_Formal\Sci.PamsPH.Payroll\PayrollP01.cs:line 350
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass42_0`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body)
   at Sci.PamsPH.Payroll.PayrollP01.ButOK_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\SystemGit2017\PamsPH_Formal\Sci.PamsPH.Payroll\PayrollP01.cs:line 201
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Ict.Win.UI.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Sci.Win.UI.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) in D:\System2017\PublicClass\Sci\Win\UI\Button.cs:line 253
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 索引超出範圍。必須為非負數且小於集合的大小。
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.RecordManager.NewRecordBase()
   at System.Data.DataTable.NewRecord(Int32 sourceRecord)
   at System.Data.DataRow.BeginEditInternal()
   at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(DataColumn column, Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(String columnName, Object value)
   at Sci.PamsPH.Payroll.PayrollP01.<ButOK_Click>b__6_1(DataRow r) in D:\SystemGit2017\PamsPH_Formal\Sci.PamsPH.Payroll\PayrollP01.cs:line 350
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass42_0`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )<---
```

If duplicate of Is Parallel.forEach(DataTable.AsEnumerable() thread safe

so I can't use Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Your actual exception is System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, so it looks like at some point you are looking up a list / array / collection using an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: if I use foreach not Parallel.ForEach, this problem will not happen.

Comment: Show us the entire method. There are a number of bugs here. For example, each of your `out` variables (e.g. `shiftID`) must be declared **inside** the `ForEach` not outside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Parallel.forEach(DataTable.AsEnumerable() thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297249/is-parallel-foreachdatatable-asenumerable-thread-safe)